# I want to setup an Ethereum Trading website. How should I handle the ETH network transaction fees (miner's fee)?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, ether, fees

Let's say Person A wants to sell 1 ETH, and Person B wants to buy 1 ETH. They agreed upon a rate. But if I transfer 1 ETH from A to B, Person B will get less than 1 ETH because of gas. But if I transfer say 1.00042 ETH from A to B, person B will get 1 ETH, but that's not fair to person A as he agreed to sell only 1 ETH.
What should I do?

Comment: If you owe $10 to a restaurant for dinner in the US and you pay by credit card, the restaurant owner pays about 80¢ to the credit card company. If you have a mail-in rebate for $10, you get $10 back after paying for postage. If you're talking to your accountant and you grab a glass of water from the accountant, the accountant is paying for your water. If you have a day job and you're paid for 8 hours of work, you still have to get to work, so you spend 9 hours doing work-related activities.

Comment: So you are saying that me(website owner) should pay the transaction fee

Comment: I’m not saying anything of the sort. I’m pointing out there are a lot of norms. This is a value-based/opinion question.

Answer (score 2):

You should make a set of rules for your users. **If you are not going to pay fees by yourself**, just add the line to user agreement about possible transaction fees. 
And be sure to specify the [range of transaction costs](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/ethereum-transactionfees.html).